# Accidently quit updating ZSH in the middle and can't type any commands

Tags: terminal, local, zsh, bin, oh-my-zsh

I was upgrading everything in homebrew and zsh was upgrading and I was cycling through my open applications and accidentally closed iterm during the update. Now I can't open iterm and when I open the terminal I get the following error message:

```
login: /usr/local/bin/zsh: No such file or directory
```

I am not sure how I can switch back to bash until I correctly update zsh. I also can't type a single command in either iterm or termianl which makes sense (there's no zsh file). How can I finish upgrading zsh correctly or switch back to bash?

I have done a good amount of research and can't find someone having a similar issue.

Any guidance to how to solve this issue would be much appreciated, I currently can't do any of the development work I need to do.

Answer (score 2):

Found this on Apple's suport site.  Basically, you want to launch Terminal and go into Preferences.  Change `Shells open with` from `Default login shell` to a valid shell (I recommend `/bin/bash` or even `/bin/sh` just to get you working again).

Once you can access your shell session, you can restore zsh.

Here's the full article... http://support.apple.com/kb/ta27005

Comment: Thank you so much Donovan! Really a life saver!